# using @starttoc causes Package tocloft Warning: \@starttoc has already been redefined;

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, thesis

I am required to use a .cls (minimized code below) which produces this warning:

**Package tocloft Warning: @starttoc has already been redefined; tocloft bailing out. on input line 1156.**

Any thoughts on how I can potentially remove this warning is appreciated.

I'm using overleaf.com (compiler == pdfLaTeX, TeX Live version == 2022)
The error log is posted below.

```
\documentclass[nopardent]{test}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Here is the minimal test.cls file

```
\ProvidesClass{test}[TEST class]
\newcommand{\classfile}{report}
\DeclareOption{nopardent}{\renewcommand{\classfile}{rapport3}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper,openright,titlepage]{\classfile}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

This is the error log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.9)  30 JUL 2023 17:20
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05> (./test.cls
Document Class: test TEST class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntgclass/rapport3.cls
Document Class: rapport3 2020-11-17 v2.1e NTG LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntgclass/ntg10.clo
File: ntg10.clo 2020-11-17 v2.1e NTG LaTeX file (size option)
)
\unitindent=\dimen138
\othermargin=\dimen139
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 818.
\bibindent=\dimen140
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocloft/tocloft.sty
Package: tocloft 2017/08/31 v2.3i parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
Package tocloft Info: The document has chapter divisions on input line 51.
\cftparskip=\skip49
\cftbeforetoctitleskip=\skip50
\cftaftertoctitleskip=\skip51
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip52
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip53
\cftpartindent=\skip54
\cftbeforechapskip=\skip55
\cftchapindent=\skip56
\cftchapnumwidth=\skip57
\cftbeforesecskip=\skip58
\cftsecindent=\skip59
\cftsecnumwidth=\skip60
\cftbeforesubsecskip=\skip61
\cftsubsecindent=\skip62
\cftsubsecnumwidth=\skip63
\cftbeforesubsubsecskip=\skip64
\cftsubsubsecindent=\skip65
\cftsubsubsecnumwidth=\skip66
\cftbeforeparaskip=\skip67
\cftparaindent=\skip68
\cftparanumwidth=\skip69
\cftbeforesubparaskip=\skip70
\cftsubparaindent=\skip71
\cftsubparanumwidth=\skip72
\cftbeforeloftitleskip=\skip73
\cftafterloftitleskip=\skip74
\cftbeforefigskip=\skip75
\cftfigindent=\skip76
\cftfignumwidth=\skip77
\c@lofdepth=\count194
\c@lotdepth=\count195
\cftbeforelottitleskip=\skip78
\cftafterlottitleskip=\skip79
\cftbeforetabskip=\skip80
\cfttabindent=\skip81
\cfttabnumwidth=\skip82

Package tocloft Warning: \@starttoc has already been redefined; tocloft bailing out. on input line 1156.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
```

Comment: packages like tocloft patch features into the standard classes, they may not work at all with other classes. It may or may not be fixable depending how your class sets up tables of contents, but you would need to show an example

Comment: you are showing a place `\@starttoc` is used but that is not related to the error, what matters is how it is (re)defined

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @DavidCarlisle - I created a minimal .tex and .cls file to reproduce the error and updated this post.

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, I'm using overleaf.com as the editor / compiler, so it seems that it is somehow pulling in that rapport3 class in the background.  Do you happen to know how I can get it from overleaf?  My overleaf project contains only two files, with the contents I posted here.  I posted the logfile above, hope this helps.

Comment: No need, it looks like it's actually part of the standard distributions.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tocloft` package checks to see whether the `\@starttoc` command has been redefined by comparing it with the kernel command. The only difference between the standard version of the command and the one defined in `rapport3` is the addition of a `\parskip\z@`.  So we can undo that change before loading `tocloft` and then reimplement it afterwards:

```
\documentclass{rapport3}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\parskip\z@}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{tocloft}
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\makeatletter}{\makeatletter\parskip\z@}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Inside a class file you don't need `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother`. So your minimal class file could look something like this:

```
\ProvidesClass{test}[TEST class]
\newcommand{\classfile}{report}
\DeclareOption{nopardent}{\renewcommand{\classfile}{rapport3}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper,openright,titlepage]{\classfile}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\parskip\z@}{}{}{\fail}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
\patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\makeatletter}{\makeatletter\parskip\z@}{}{\fail}
% rest of class file here
\endinput % end of class file
```

Comment: Thanks!

I am having trouble figuring out how to modify the .cls or .tex file in the question above to make this work. 

I keep getting 'LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.' or  'LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.'  when I put it in either. 

Do you happen to know how to merge it into the .cls?

Comment: Inside the class you don't need `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`. And it's best to use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`.   I've updated the answer. Also, please use the slightly edited version of the code.

Comment: It seems that the \endinput line causes an ERROR in a .tex file during compilation.  (even with the updated code).

Removing \endinput seems to make it all work though - would it make sense to update the answer?

Comment: @me_online I just put it there to denote the end of the class file, but it's not crucial.  I've made the code a bit clearer.